# iOS Force GCM to refresh registration token

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I use **GCM** in my Swift app and would like to ask GCM a new registration token.

I know that it's done automatically by GCM and I handle it in **onTokenRefresh**, but I want to know if it's possible to **request GCM to refresh the token manually** (to have a different one).

I tried to unregister for remote notification and register back to run the process (**tokenWithAuthorizedEntity** etc ...) but the registration token sent is the same.

any solution to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `deleteTokenWithAuthorizedEntity:` method before asking for a new token as derived [in the official docs](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/ios-implementation#delete_tokens_and_product_names). Also, if that fails, delete the Instance ID itself, which will delete all tokens associated with that Instance ID, in which case make sure to also call `getIDWithHandler:` before asking for a new token.

Anyway, why do you need to refresh this token? Although you can delete them, this is not their intended use. If you're just looking to ID a particular device uniquely, use the Instance ID itself OR use alternate methods of generating random strings (and then re checking if this random string has actually never been generated and used before).

Comment: Thank's it works by delete Instance ID. I juste wanted to be able to ask a new token if needed in my app. Thank's